# take WebView's URL from JSON

Tags: android, mysql, json, webview

MY JOSON: http://yazbiryere.com/Ozkan356.php

variable in the URL of the picture , I want to show the webwiev

[image]

how can I do it.

Comment: You must parse Json. Then You will receive  value : " id, ad, soyad, dtarihi, kilo,boy"

Comment: soyad , it is the link you need to show to the webview

Comment: I do not know how to get

Comment: you can search google !!!.

Comment: I can not do it all for you. Please do. If an error arises, I will help you